# Start/Pause the timer on click events

Tags: angular, typescript, countdowntimer

I want to start the timer on the start , which will be in the format MM:SS after an hour format should look like HH:MM:SS. on pause the timer should stop again . User can start/Pause any time the timer should continue from the last time it was paused.

```
start(){
setInterval(()=>{
let timer = 0;
let minutes = 0 ;
let hour = 0 ;
let seconds = 0;

if(seconds > 3600){ // to increment the hour value

}

if( minutes < 60){ // to calculate minutes
}

concole.log(timer); //to get timer value in format MM:SS and HH:MM:SS 

},1000)

}

pauseTimer(){
// need to implement logic
}
```

Need to implement a logic to get a timer continue/pause. I am getting confused to implement login for start and pause function.

Comment: Check this link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cd-timer

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with angular by using following code..
```

1. TimerComponent.ts

---

```
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit 
{

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

      timer:string="";
      minutes = 0;
      hour = 0;
      seconds = 0;

       setTimer:string=""; 
       isStart:boolean=false;
       timerInterval:any;

  start()
{
    this.isStart=true;
      this.timerInterval=setInterval(() => {
     
      if (this.minutes > 59) { // to increment the hour value
        this.hour=this.hour+1;
        this.seconds=0;
        this.minutes=0;
      }

      if (this.seconds > 59) { // to calculate minutes
        this.minutes=this.minutes+1;
        this.seconds=0;
      }
      
      this.seconds=this.seconds+1;
      
      console.log(  this.timer=`${this.hour}:${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`); //to get timer value in format MM:SS and HH:MM:SS 
    }, 1000)

  }

  

    pauseTimer() {
        // need to implement logic
        this.isStart=false;
        this.setTimer=this.timer; 
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
      }

}
```

2. TimerComponent.html

---

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row ">
        <label for="">{{timer}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="start()" [disabled]="isStart">
                Start Timer
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary mx-5" (click)="pauseTimer()">
                Pause Timer
            </button>
        </div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="">{{setTimer}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way, no formatting included.

```js
  timer = 0; // seconds
  intervalId = 0;

  get hours() {
    return Math.floor(this.timer / 3600);
  }

  get minutes() {
    return Math.floor(this.timer / 60) % 60;
  }

  get seconds() {
    return this.timer % 60;
  }

  start() {
    if (!this.intervalId)
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.timer++, 1000);
  }

  stop() {
    if (this.intervalId) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      this.intervalId = 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<p>{{ hours }}:{{ minutes }}:{{ seconds }}</p>
<button (click)="start()">START</button>
<button (click)="stop()">STOP</button>
```

Comment: Type ‘Timer’ is not accessible to type ‘number’ error for intervalId variable @chris

Comment: @Santhosh There is no `Timer` type in my code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-udkan7?file=src/app/app.component.ts